# how to plink execute cmd

Tags: python, windows, syntax, cmd, plink

I have to use plink to execute cmd to unzip file by using a 7z.exe at remote desktop

> C:\windows\system32>C:/E2EPerformance/tool/PROD/STCP/BreadcrumbCollector/binary/plink.exe -ssh -l admin -pw pass IP cmd.exe /c cd 7z.exe x D:/PostProcess/Processed/20150417_01.zip -oD:/PostProcess/Processed/temp

it's procedure error :

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

and

> C:\windows\system32>C:/E2EPerformance/tool/PROD/STCP/BreadcrumbCollector/binary/
>   plink.exe -ssh -l admin -pw pass IP cmd.exe /c 7z.exe x D:/P
>   ostProcess/Processed/20150417_01.zip -oD:/PostProcess/Processed/temp

I got: Access is denied. but I accessed to remote desktop

> C:\windows\system32>C:/E2EPerformance/tool/PROD/STCP/BreadcrumbCollector/binary/
>   plink.exe -ssh -l admin -pw pass IP cmd.exe /c del /PostProc
>   ess/Processed/temp/test

I got: Parameter format not correct - "PostProcess".

Comment: These are three separate problems. Neither seem to have anything to do with plink or python. It's all about the syntax of the command you are executing on the remote desktop. And it's off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I used plink in my python script and i copies ''command'' from script. you don't see plink? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I see Plink, but your have the Windows command syntax wrong. It wouldn't work even if you run it locally on the remote desktop. What should be the first thing your should have tried, even before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses backslashes for paths. Forward slash for switch (although command.com is switchable between forward slash and dash). It encloses paths and parameters with spaces in quotes. While we have various ways to find files the only sure way is specify full paths.

If you are an admin just put the files on the other computer. Use `\\server\share\path`.

```
copy "c:\MyHardDrive\somefile.ext" \\RemoteComputerName\C$\RemoteHardDrive\Somefile.ext
```

Also wmic can also execute remotely. Note backslash is escaped.

```
wmic /node:RemoteComputerName process call create "c:\\PathToRemote7Zip\\7Zip.exe C:\\RemoteHardDrive\\Somefile.zip C:\\RemoteHardDrive\\Somefile.ext
```

or

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "c:\\PathToRemote7Zip\\7Zip.exe C:\\RemoteHardDrive\\Somefile.zip C:\\RemoteHardDrive\\Somefile.ext
```

WMIC also has user and password switches.

Comment: thank you but i think that i got a new trouble : > Description = The RPC server is unavailable.

Comment: It requires windows networking. I don't know python but it looks C ish. Try the path with correct windows paths and also with escaped backslashes (which a c program would require).